# Windows batch combining coffee-script, copy and uglyify

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, coffeescript

So im trying to write a nice batch file to combine my javascript libraries, combine and compile my .coffee files, combine the both results and then minify it with uglyify.
However im running into some problems with my batch file; after my coffee command the batchfile stops running. I don't get any error or something.

This is my file structure

```
batch.bat
src/
     coffee/
             1.coffee
             2.coffee
     js/
             1.js
             2.js
```

This is the content of my batch file

```
mkdir temp
coffee --output temp --join coffee.js --compile src\coffee
copy /b src\js temp\javascript.js
copy /b temp\javascript.js+temp\coffee.js temp\min.js
uglifyjs -o  javascript.js temp\min.js
```

As said when i run this from the console the mkdir command gets executed, the coffee script runs and finishes and then the batch just stops. 
I tested the commands manually and the commands themself work as i would expect them to.

This is the result i see in the console:

```
C:\User>mkdir temp
C:\User>coffee --output temp --join coffee.js --compile src\coffee
C:\User>_
```

My thoughts are that maybe the coffee command runs async and the copy command cannot find the required files to combine and then can't do the other commands because of the missing files. I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem so far..

Comment: Have you considered writing a [Cakefile](http://coffeescript.org/#cake)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in your terminology - coffee-`SCRIPT`

Since it's evidently a BATCH file, you need to `CALL` it

```
mkdir temp
CALL coffee --output temp --join coffee.js --compile src\coffee
copy /b src\js temp\javascript.js
copy /b temp\javascript.js+temp\coffee.js temp\min.js
uglifyjs -o  javascript.js temp\min.js
```

You could also `CALL` the `UGLIFYJS` as well if you wish - but as it's the last command, it will make no difference.

CALL sets a return location to resume processing when the script finishes.

Comment: Thank you! I knew this was needed for other scripts but it sounds very logical. Worked like a charm!